# Shared Internet access not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection

I am trying to set up the Internet connection for my company.

What I want to do:
Internet → DSL modem w/wireless and four-port LAN (allow free wireless for customers) → "Desktop 1" → Router w/wireless and four-port switch LAN (secured business network) → ["wireless notebook 1" and "desktop 2"]

What I have currently:
"Desktop 1" has access to network and Internet

"Desktop 2" has access to network (I don't want Internet access on this system and thus have not tried to set it up)

"Wireless notebook 1" has access to the network but is unable to gain access to the Internet

Purpose:
I am slightly anal, especially when it comes to the business computer system. I want everything to be secured behind firewalls, and I want to use "Desktop 1" as a front runner just to add to the security. I want the business network to be secured and "hidden" even though I understand wireless systems can "see" it but not access it. I want the DSL, which acts like a wireless router, to be configured for free unsecured Internet for our customers... or I could put a simple password on it.

Equipment:
All systems are running Windows XP Pro; "Desktop 1" has two NIC cards; I tried to share both, but had no luck.

Comment: Why not just buy a router that has the functionality you require? Or, as others have said, buy a cheap router that you can install DD-WRT on and it'll do what you want? Your current setup relies on a workstation being on even when you don't want to use it... There are plenty of available items, such brands include DrayTek? They let you easily create two VLANs (guest & office) and they're separated by one device and give you the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to have for the customer's wireless AP to be in isolated mode - that will ensure that customers will be able to logon to your free wifi and internet, without seeing any other computers on the network (not even each other's).

That way, customers who go on the Customer-Wifi is in isolated mode and can't see anything else - your business network however is intact, and you can go ahead and configure/lock-down to your heart content.

I recommend DD-WRT with a compatible router for serving your customers' Internet needs. Remember, keyword is "isolation mode"

Comment: Well thank you for this; this is some additional information for me that I haven't even gotten to or consider YET! - so notted for the future.

The big issue that I am dealing with right now and wan't to solve; I cannot get "wireless notebook1" to use my "Desktop 1" shared internet connection
                      - this is the problem I need help to solve -

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the second router is in NOT configured as a DHCP server, and you are not connecting the network to it's WAN port. That is the simplest way with the setup you described. As described by the other answer, this is not necessarily secure, and I'd also suggest thinking about using DD-WRT.

Comment: Alright have set my "secured Network" Router to DHCP OFF; this has no apparent affect still not able to connect to shared internet connection; I am wondering what I need for ip addresses; do I need to 'dial in' the Wireless Notebook to my Desktops Default Gateway or IP or something?

Comment: Hmm Ok, What routers do you have? I'll also try work it with the firewalls and extra security.

Comment: I am using a Belkin N wireless router and a Telus wireless Modem

Comment: I noticed after turning DHCP OFF that the Wireless Notebook would not connect to my network either... almost seems like I am going backwards on this one can any one help?